# Angular 2 POST Request

Tags: http, angular, post

While doing the POST request in Angular 2, I am getting:

> "EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL:" .

However, while accessing the URL directly, I am getting the response page.

Also in my backend code, I can see my data getting passed from client side to server side:

> Response_body: "{"Message":"Not able to add Language = A"}"
>   headers: Headersok: false
>   status: 404
>   statusText: "Not Found"
>   type: 2
>   url: "http://localhost:1109/api/Language/AddLanguage"

```
onSubmit(val){
   console.log(val);
   this.languageService.testPost(val)
        .subscribe(
         (res:response) => console.log(res);
        );
}                

testPost(newVal) : Observable<any>{
    let body = JSON.stringify(newVal);
    console.log(body);
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type' : 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers : headers});
    return this.http.post(this.logUrl,body,options)
        .map((res : Response) =>  res.json());
}
```

Comment: Error in Request are : Response_body: "{"Message":"Not able to add Language = A"}"
headers: Headersok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
type: 2
url: "http://localhost:1109/api/Language/AddLanguage"

Comment: can you provide the code or create a plukr ?

Comment: "While Doing the POST Request (...) However,while Accessing the URL Directly" When you acces directly the request in a browser, you make a GET request, not a POST...

Comment: @oreofeolurin...here you go:testPost(newVal) : Observable<any>{
   let body = JSON.stringify(newVal);
   console.log(body);
  let headers = new Headers({
           'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
  });
  let options = new RequestOptions({
           headers : headers
  });
  return this.http.post(this.logUrl,body,options)
  .map((res : Response) =>  res.json());
 }

Comment: onSubmit(val){

     console.log(val);
     this.languageService.testPost(val)
                   .subscribe(
                       (res:response) => console.log(res);
                       );
    }

Comment: @user3856563 please post the code to your question instead of comment, thank you!

Comment: @Karbos.....yeas Karbos,I am saying URL is accessebile

Comment: But your ressource must match with a method AND an url. Maybe in your case there is also a constraint with headers besause your server is responding `Headersok: false`. You can try your request with a REST client like *PostMan* or *Advanced Rest Client* plugin in Chrome

Comment: This is a very generic error, anything could be wrong from server side ranging from incorrect connection string to stack-overflow exception. I encourage you to check the error logs of the server code (if the server code is logging somewhere and you have access to it) and paste the error here (if any). If nothing else atleast you'll be sure that the server side code is working fine and you require to focus on JS tweaking.

Comment: @RachitPandey...Yes Rachit,I think you are correct.While Debugging,In my Server side Code I found an Exception mentioning Too many Arguments while saving Data To Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes Rachit,I think you are correct.While Debugging,In my Server side Code I found an Exception mentioning Too many Arguments while saving Data To Database.

There's the culprit I believe, this error generally occurs if you supply more than required params to an SP. So in your DB implementation if you are using SP(s) kindly check them one by one which one is supplying extra parameters. And if nothing else is the problem you should have this issue resolved.

Comment: Bang On!!!!.....You saved my Day Rachit. The Issue was same as Expected by You. While Analysing the S.P and backend Code,found the Culprit was Addition of an Extra Parameter.Removing the Line,did the Trick. Thanks a lot.